# Creating a copy of a column within the same dataframe and then dropping the original column deletes the copied column as well

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

This is my original dataframe-
[Original dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4MbU.png)

I created a copy of the column 'spx' within the same dataframe using assign-
[Creating copy of column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5d3v.png)

Subsequently, I dropped 'spx' along with a few other redundant columns. After this I found out that the new column which I had created got deleted as well-
[After dropping columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlSBn.png)

I wish to retain the column 'market_value' even after dropping 'spx'. Please point out the way forward and the mistake which I have been making. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add the code itself, not as images (to make it easier for us to help you & not to attract downvotes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have:

```
df_comp = df_comp.assign(market_value=df_comp['spx'])
```

This is the case because `df_comp.assign(market_value=df_comp['spx'])` does not happen inplace, so without the `df_comp =` in the beginning, `df_comp` is not modified (ie you do not add `market_value` column to the original `df`: it just returns a `df` where it is added, but that is not the original).

Comment: Does he need to `reset_index()` his dataframe before working on that df?

Comment: If OP wants the original index (ie `date`) to be a column, then yes. Make sure the `df` where the index is actually reset is the original dataframe, if that is the intention.